# ec2 ssh Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions, public-key

Two days ago, I tried to connect to the server with ssh as usual. But I got a connection refused error.

I've tried a lot of solutions. As in this youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_P29ZHu_feU), I tried to solve the problem by attaching the problem server to a running server. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=145071 I applied the solution here.

```
chown root: root/var/empty/sshd
chmod 711 /var/empty/sshd
```

Then I did a detach of the problematic server's volume and did it again to the problematic server. The server was running smoothly when I started the server, but I couldn't connect with ssh again.

Then, as described here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair), I did the problematic server's volume attaching to a seamless server. Then I smoothly installed the server's authorized_keys on the problem server, and again I started to detach-attach server. But this was not a solution.

I'm still getting the Permission denied (publickey) error.

I have no idea how to solve this problem, why the solution manufacturer.

Is there anyone who has an idea about this? Please help :(

DEBUG

```
$ ssh -v KEY.pem ec2-user@IP
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to KEY.pem port 22.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname KEY.pem: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong - it thinks "KEY.pem" is the host you are trying to connect to. Should be:

```
ssh -v -i KEY.pem ec2-user@IP
```

Comment: nothing has changed. I've tried this before.